# Customize boring layout

Tags: cakephp

Hi may i know how to customize the Cakephp interface layout? I would like my cake app layout to at least look something like this http://chocotemplates.com/preview/gui/spring-time/#
1) how to remove the left action button?
2) how to add the tab button at the header page?
3) Add margin * auto to make the site have left and right margin and make the body centered.

I have tried to change and i could not find the necessary file which allow me to edit these simple things above. Please advice.

My boring app print screen 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CakePhp is a framework, not a CMS =)**

you have probably used the `bake` function to create the Views, well first you'll need to redefine the layout so you could add the css/js files you'll need (in "/views/layouts").. and also to define the id's and class names of your elements.

so basically all you need to do is to modify your html/css manually in the views (.ctp files inside the /views folder).

But maybe you want to [redefine the way that cake create the views when baking](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/rascoop/2010/06/02/custom-baking-with-cakephp-1-3). Maybe there are some good samaritans on the internet that share their templates with the world.

Hope this helps =)

Answer (score 1):

a) change the layout
/views/layouts/default.ctp

b) use custom templates for the views:
http://www.dereuromark.de/tag/custom-template/

you can change just about anything.